# Rewriting partitions using exponents

Tags: output-formatting, combinatorics, partitions

I'm looking for a way to re-express a partition given in full form, like 
$\{{2, 2, 1, 1}\}$, into the shortened form $\{2^2, 1^2\}$, *i.e.* given a partition with repeated entries, count the number of repetitions of a given entry, and convert this (without evaluating the $a^b$) to exponential form.

I'm aware that "Tally" will produce the correct count:

```
Tally[{2,2,1,1}]
```

correctly returns $\{\{2,2\},\{1,2\}\}$ but converting this to $2^2 1^2$ is the part that gives me trouble.

A final refinement would be that, when $1$ occurs as an exponent, it is NOT displayed, i.e. $\{4,1,1\}$ is displayed in shortened form as $\{4, 1^2\}$.  The separation by "," is optional but if the entries are in the double digits it makes a little more sense to have the ",".

Comment: Removed my comment, but a polished version now as an answer. :)

Comment: @kirma yes the addition of the thin space is a nice touch as it will obviously separate entries even is they contain more than 1 digit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DisplayForm@RowBox@
  Riffle[If[#2 == 1, #1, #1^#2] & @@@
    Tally[HoldForm /@ {2, 2, 1, 50, 50, 50}],
   "\[ThinSpace]"]
```

> $2^2\, 1\, 50^3$

You can also apply `TraditionalForm` and `TeXForm` gracefully on this (but only after `DisplayForm`.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

Fix issue pointed out by @ZeroTheHero

```
Tally[{2, 2, 1, 1}] /. {x_Integer, y_Integer} :> If[y == 1, y, Defer[x^y]]
(* {2^2, 1^2} *)
```

---

```
Tally[{2, 2, 1, 1}] /. {x_Integer, y_Integer} :> If[x == 1, x, Defer[x^y]]

(* {2^2, 1} *)
```

Comment: This doesn’t quite work as the output should be {2^2,1^2}.  I suspect your condition on x should be on the exponent y instead.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You are right, I misinterpreted the question. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: no worries.  Thanks for fixing.  Also a nice solution.

Answer (score 6):

This may be useful:

```
Times @@ HoldForm /@ {2, 2, 1, 50, 50, 50}
```

> 1 2<sup>2</sup> 50<sup>3</sup>

Comment: Interesting way to handle exponents, but I wonder if ordering of these items is important...

Comment: @kirma In a partition the entry at position $i$ is necessarily greater or equal to the following entry at position $i+1$, so there's an implicit (partial) ordering of entries.

Answer (score 6):

```
Defer @* Power @@@ Tally[{2, 2, 1, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {2^2, 1^2, 3^1}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a very simple answer would be enough. I suggest

```
Times@@ToString /@ {2, 2, 1, 50, 50, 50}
```

which returns

$$ 1\, 2^2\, 50^3 $$